# Lock-free bounded stack atomics

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, stack, lock-free

I was thinking about using very basic bounded (preallocated) stack to keep track of my threads IDs in correct LIFO order. I was wondering if my implementation is thread safe:

```
// we use maximum 8 workers
size_t idle_ids_stack[8];
// position current write happening at
std::atomic_uint_fast8_t idle_pos(0);

// this function is called by each thread when it is about to sleep
void register_idle(size_t thread_id) 
{
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
    idle_ids_stack[idle_pos.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)] = thread_id;
}

// this function can be called from anywhere at anytime
void wakeup_one() 
{
    uint_fast8_t old_pos(idle_pos.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    size_t id;
    do
    {
        if(old_pos == 0) return; // no idle threads in stack; exit;
        id = idle_ids_stack[old_pos-1];
    }
    while (!idle_pos.compare_exchange_weak(old_pos, old_pos-1, std::memory_order_acquire, std::memory_order_relaxed));
    // wakeup single thread
    signal_thread(id);
}
```

---

Please see latest changes: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/inspirit/a14b0a1f227a2d288b46)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem 1

Consider that `register_idle()` is equivalent to this slightly rewritten version:

```
// this function is called by each thread when it is about to sleep
void register_idle(size_t thread_id) 
{
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
    uint8_t pos = idle_pos.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);

    // What happens when this thread stops right here?

    idle_ids_stack[pos] = thread_id;
}
```

If the thread stops after incrementing `idle_pos`, but before writing the actual thread id to the stack, you will be in trouble when another thread tries to wake up the thread at the top of stack.  It will try to read a thread id from the stack that has not yet been written.

### Problem 2

(Credit @MikeMB for correcting me on my previous answer)

You have a problem in `wakeup_one()` as well.  Suppose `idle_pos` is 2 and `idle_ids_stack[1]` is 5.  Now consider the following sequence of events:

1. Thread 1 runs `wakeup_one()` and executes `id = idle_ids_stack[old_pos-1]`, so at this point, `id` is 5.  But now thread 1 sleeps for a little while.
2. Thread 2 runs `wakeup_one()`, grabs the same `id` (5), and returns it, setting `idle_pos` to 1 in the process.
3. Thread 3 runs `register_idle()`, puts its `id` (3) into `idle_ids_stack[1]` and increments `idle_pos` back to 2.
4. Now thread 1 resumes, and compare-exchanges `idle_pos` from 2 to 1 successfully.  But it returns `id` as 5 (a duplicate thread id), instead of 3 (the proper one).

Comment: Regarding problem2: `compare_exchange_weak` does update the first argument with the current value of the atomic variable. In this case, `old_pos` IS set to the value of `idle_pos` in every iteration. However, that still leaves Problem 1 and the ABA problem (see [my answer at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921411/lock-free-bounded-stack-c11-atomics/30925869#30925869) - is there a way to merge those questions?).

Comment: regarding 2: yes it will be updated thanx to compare_exchange. still the first problem remains... looks like there is no easy solution. i have to consider using Node based approach with tags or hazard pointers

Comment: @MikeMB Oops sorry, I will correct this.

Comment: @inspirit Why not just use a lock/mutex?

Comment: @JS1 yes thats what i did already of course. now i was trying to optimize some of the parts including thread lifecycle management.

Comment: @MikeMB i have updated the code with additional version. can u please review? thanx.

Comment: @inspirit: If I've time, I can have a look at it over the weekend, but I believe it is the policy here is to open up a new question for a revised version of your code. Aside from this, you should additionally check the following (if you haven't done this already): Do you actually need, the additional performance of lockfree code? Is the lockfree code actually faster than a version with locks (This is NOT guaranteed, especially, if you have to dynamically allocate memory).

Comment: @MikeMB okay i will move it to new question. apart from that the question now is correct stack implementation not if it will be faster in my specific use. the implementation i provide uses preallocated buffer so it should not suffer from dynamic allocation... new link: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94086/c11-lock-free-bounded-stack